# Database design: should nested objects have their own table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I'm somewhat new to database design, so I'd like some pointers on how best to lay my current tables out.

I have a table `Jobs` that holds various jobs. Users can create `Subjobs`. A `Subjob` has a `Job` as a parent. A `Subjob` has all the same properties as a `Job`, but some of them are read-only, whereas they are all read/write for a `Job`. A `Job` can have many `Subjobs`. At the moment, there may only be one layer of subjobs, but I'd like the flexibility to allow for infinite nesting of `Subjobs` in the future. The objects will be interacted with through a MVC web app.

I've considered two options for layout:

- `Jobs` and `Subjobs` each have their own table.

  - This seems like "good design" because I don't introduce columns in `Job` with the sole purpose of nesting with itself.
  - It's a bit of a pain for coding the web app, since a `Job` and `Subjob` would have to have two separate Controllers/sets of Views, despite them being identical in properties.
  - It makes less sense from a design perspective if infinite nesting is introduced.
- `Jobs` and `Subjobs` are on the same table. `Jobs` are just given a nullable `parent_job_id` property that is non-null if it is a `Subjob`.

  - Makes sense for infinite nesting.
  - Less of a pain for coding the web app.
  - A weird nesting property is introduced to the `Job` table that has nothing to do with the actual properties of a `Job`.

Any advice on how to handle this? Are there additional design patterns I haven't considered? I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is fine if you were not describing a hierarchy with multiple levels, but you are. The pattern you are describing is commonly known as an *Adjacency List* which is stored as you describe your second option.

Some other options for storing a hierarchy are:

- Nested sets (more complicated implementation but potentially faster queries without recursion).
- Materialized Path (Stores a character representation of the hierarchy path, e.g. like a file storage system)
- Modifications / Helper tables for Adjacency List (Flat table, bridge table)
- Custom implementations like [HierarchyId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference)

Hierarchy Reference:

- [StackOverflow - What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational-database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/2333499)
- [Louis Davidson - Presentations - How to Optimize a Hierarchy In SQL Server - Presentations & Demo Code](http://www.drsql.org/presentations)

Comment: Well done. I was writing a comment to much the same but this is far more robust than I was going to list. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks! Pretty much an soft introduction to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/2333499 with some general observations.